# Changing the repository to upgrade

Tags: upgrade, repository, release-management

For upgrading a release (e.g. from Quantal to Raring), `apt-get dist-upgrade` does work. I wonder what happens if simply changing the repository (e.g. from Quantal to Raring) then utilizing normal `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`?

Changing

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main
```

to

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main
```

then

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Can this method actually upgrade to the latest release of ubuntu?

I am curious what happens by this approach.

Answer (score 0):

`upgrade` refuses add or remove packages, even if they are required by or conflict with new versions of packages to be upgraded, thus, you must use `dist-upgrade` or you will end up with a partially upgraded system.